# SharePoint Server 2010: Problem getting detailed error messages

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I'm pretty new to SharePoint and IIS, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this one. I'm deploying a custom ASPX with code-behind to my SharePoint server and need a detailed stack trace to see where my problems are.

This involves modifying the web.config file and setting three attributes of certain tags: `<SafeMode CallStack="true" AllowPageLevelTrace="true" />` and `<CustomErrors mode="Off" />`. There are lots of different web.config files, but my error messages change when I modify a certain one, indicating that I chose the right file to edit.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax5vv.png)

The problem, however, is that when I do change these tags, I only get an error message telling me the stack trace cannot be displayed remotely, even if I try to display the page on the server itself. The error message basically tells me that in order to get the complete stack trace, I have to do what I just did: Set CustomErrors mode="Off".

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen before, but only with certain types of errors (HttpModules).

Try checking the windows event log for a more detailed message. It should be there.

Also try restarting IIS/server to make sure its clean/all services are started.